# Какую связь нужно применить в модели Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, orm, model, relation

Существуют модели `Privilege`, `GameBoard`, `Card`.

Хочу реализовать связь между этими моделями следующим образом:
У модели `Privilege` есть связь `FK(ForeignKey)` с `GameBoard`.

Сами карточки `Card`, тесно связаны с `GameBoard`, то есть, если удалить доску, то карточки все зависящие от этой доски также удаляться. 
Этот механизм я сделал с помощью связи `FK` и флажком `on_delete=models.CASCADE` в модели `Card`.

Но еще карточкам доступны привилегии которые берутся у доски `Privilege.objects.filter(game_board_id=1).all()`

Но при этом в настройках карточки можно отключать данные привилегии. Именно данный функционал и связь еще не реализована. Теперь сам вопрос:

Чтобы это реализовать, мне нужно будет создать связь `ManyToMany` с моделью `Card` в модели `Privilege`?

Comment: Если у карточки может быть много привелегий, то да

Comment: Либо сделать m2m в Card к привелегиям